# Queryset in view or in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to speed up my code. In development, everything ran very smooth, but once I put it in production, and started adding more depth of data into the database, I realize that it is running very slow.

I noticed on django-toolbar that it is running THOUSANDS of queries, where it should only be maybe 10-20. I am wondering if it may be because of the way I have a lot of content being delivered.

For example, I have code that looks like this:

```
{% if user.profile.is_admin %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% for stuff in user.profile.get_somestuff %}
   ...
   {{ stuff.info }}
   {{ stuff.other_info }}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Does each one of these execute a new query?

Should I run the query for `get_somestuff` in the view, pass it through context? I am asking from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `profile.get_somestuff` is an expensive operation and you call it multiple times in the template, and yes, you should call that in the view once and pass the result to the template via `context`.

```
def view(request):
    ...
    stuff = request.user.profile.get_somestuff()
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'stuff': stuff})
```

Alternatively, you can use [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag to create a scope containing the value in its own context:

```
{% with stuff=user.profile.get_somestuff %}
   ...
   {{ stuff.info }}
   {{ stuff.other_info }}
   ... do some other things with stuff
{% endwith %}
```

Personally, I would go with the first option because, with the help of `django.db.connection.queries`, it is relatively easier to monitor db queries you make in the view. Make sure you avoid sending template  querysets, lazy expressions etc. as much as possible.

BTW, please note that `DEBUG` must be set to `True` for `connection.queries` to work.

Comment: I have a feeling this is exactly my problem. Looks like I have a LOT of optimizing ahead of me to fix all my mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

If stuff.info or stuff.other_info are foreign keys to other models then yes, each time you hit each of those for a new stuff obj you could be doing another select query for each one.

select_related might help you here. It'll effectively join the relevant tables on the fk fields you specify in the sql query upfront. The sql query will be more complex than the queries you're running now but far less numerous.